# Check if object is in another queryset?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I'm losing my mind on why this doesn't work as expected.

I have a many to many relationship between **songs** and **weeks**, which are unified in a **position** model which stores the position of the song for the week.

In the view I try to see if a song from this week is in the last_week but it says it never is, which isn't the expected result.

Model:

```
class Song(models.Model):
    name = models.CharField(max_length=300)
    artist = models.CharField(max_length=300)

    def __unicode__(self):
        return self.name

class Week(models.Model):
    date = models.DateField()
    songs = models.ManyToManyField('Song', through="Position")
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.date)

class Position(models.Model):
    week = models.ForeignKey('Week')
    song = models.ForeignKey('Song')
    position = models.SmallIntegerField();
    def __unicode__(self):
        return unicode(self.week.date) + " " + unicode(self.song.name)
```

View:

```
def changed_since_last_week(request):
    week = Week.objects.all().reverse()[0]
    last_week = Week.objects.all().reverse()[1]
    songs = week.songs.all()
    last_week_songs = last_week.songs.all()
    context_dict = {"songs": songs}
    for song in songs:
        if song in last_week_songs: #This never gets executed!
            song.change = Position.objects.get(week=last_week,song=song).position-Position.objects.get(week=week,song=song).position
        else:
            song.attr = "New entry"
    return render(request, 'charts/change.html', context_dict)
```

Shell:

```
>>> song = Week.objects.all()[0].songs.all()[0]
>>> song
<Song: Uptown Funk!>
>>> song in Week.objects.all()[1].songs.all()
False
>>> Week.objects.all()[1].songs.all()
[<Song: Blank Space>, <Song: Uptown Funk!>'...(remaining elements truncated)...']
>>>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that part is the problem. You don't define any ordering on `Week`, so you can in no way guarantee that you get the correct week objects. Use `.order_by('-date')` or define `ordering` in your `Meta` class.

`x in y` returns `True` if `y` contains a model with the same concrete model, `x.pk is not None` and `x.pk == y.pk`.

Comment: I changed it. And the week and last_week are definitely present, but still the if never gets executed.  Thanks for the effort, though.

Comment: @Igor Of course they are present, but are they the right `Week` object? I don't see anything else wrong with your code. How do you confirm that the code is indeed never executed?

Comment: I put a print after the if statement, and also in the view every song has a new attr added to it in the else.

Comment: Can you confirm that the songs in `songs` and `last_week_songs` have overlapping primary keys? Maybe you're creating a new song each week with the same name and artist.

Comment: No, because if I do get_or_create on `Song.objects.get_or_create(name=name, artist=artist)` it gives errors. However if I do only `create` it gives no errors.

Comment: What kind of errors? It's not supposed to give any errors.

Comment: Thank you. The problem was in the way I populated the database.   Can you confirm that the songs in songs and last_week_songs have overlapping primary keys? Maybe you're creating a new song each week with the same name and artist. –  knbk 27 mins ago 
This was the kicker which solved the problem. Thank you!